Polars - can't compute entropy after conversion to pl.List
I'm trying to compute the entropy of a list, but I need to do a conversion first :
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"Result": "1, 2, 3"})

df.select(pl.col("Result").str.split(",").cast(pl.List(pl.Float64)).entropy()).collect()

but this gives :
ComputeError: cannot cast List type (inner: 'Float64', to: 'Float64')

What's wrong here?

what version of polars is this being run on?

@CameronRiddell 0.20.2, and this is running inside google colab.

For this problem you’ll need to do a couple of things:

properly parse the numbers (including the space after the comma)
use .list.eval(…entropy()) to calculate the entropy per list
the result returns a list of length 1, so we grab the calculated entropy

import polars as pl
print(pl.__version__) # 0.20.2

df = pl.DataFrame({"Result": ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"]})

print(
    df.select(
        pl.col("Result").str.split(", ")   # ①
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Float64))
        .list.eval(pl.element().entropy()) # ②
        .list.get(0)                       # ③
    )
    # shape: (2, 1)
    # ┌──────────┐
    # │ Result   │
    # │ ---      │
    # │ f64      │
    # ╞══════════╡
    # │ 1.011404 │
    # │ 1.085189 │
    # └──────────┘
)


why do we need to operate on the pl.element() level when entropy itself is an operation on the whole array? seems like a strange design choice. thank you for the answer and +1 :))

@AnthonyML .list.eval is a fallback approach for when there is no dedicated list function. .list.entropy() does not exist. (From a quick search on the Github tracker - it doesn't look like anybody has requested it as of yet.)

pl.element is a bit if a misnomer. It operates on each list at a time rather than each scalar element.
